# Сложность вывода значений полей плагина SimpleFields

Tags: wordpress

Установил и настроил плагин SimpleFields. var_dump(WP_Query()) выдает список полей, сделанные, так же, этим плагином. Но вывести, при помощи функций плагина, не получается - выдает ошибку:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simple_field_value()
```

Код вывода полей:

```
//$field_value = simple_field_value("name_home");   // name_home - слаг одного из полей
$field_value = simple_fields_value("property_fields"); // property_fields - слаг группы полей
echo "The field has the value: $field_value";
```

Почему у меня выдает undefined function?

Делал все по документации:

```
https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-fields/
```

Comment: Не стоит пользоваться плагинами, которые уже 2 года не обновляются. А откуда вы делаете этот вызов?

Comment: @KAGG Design, из файла index.php, на главной странице. В таске указано использовать этот плагин.

Comment: И делаете это, наверное, до строчки `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Comment: Код index.php покажете?